# All rank quotes at the end of the game?

Tags: civilization-5

When the game ends, depend on your score you get a "General" rank like Ceaser, Ivan the Terrible, etc, along with a quote. It would take a lot of time to get all of these quotes by myself and it's not easy to get each different quote based on my score at the end of the game.

Can you give me all the quotes please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quotes can be found in XML\NewText\EN_US\CIV5GameTextInfos_Jon.xml.  Sorry about the lack of formatting, this is just a direct copy/paste from the current version of the file.

```
<!-- Dan Quayle Screen -->
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_1">
  <Text>Augustus Caesar</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_1_QUOTE">
  <Text>I found Rome a city of bricks and left it a city of
  marble.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_2">
  <Text>Hammurabi</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_2_QUOTE">
  <Text>When Marduk sent me to rule over men, to give the
  protection of right to the land, I did right and righteousness,
  and brought about the well-being of the oppressed.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_3">
  <Text>Abraham Lincoln</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_3_QUOTE">
  <Text>Always bear in mind that your own resolution to succeed is
  more important than any other.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_4">
  <Text>Charlemagne</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_4_QUOTE">
  <Text>Let my armies be the rocks and the trees, and the birds in
  the sky.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_5">
  <Text>Winston Churchill</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_5_QUOTE">
  <Text>A pessimist sees the difficulty in every opportunity; an
  optimist sees the opportunity in every difficulty.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_6">
  <Text>Nelson Mandela</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_6_QUOTE">
  <Text>It always seems impossible until its done.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_7">
  <Text>Marcus Aurelius</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_7_QUOTE">
  <Text>Because a thing seems difficult for you, do not think it
  impossible for anyone to accomplish.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_8">
  <Text>Joan of Arc</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_8_QUOTE">
  <Text>I am not afraid... I was born to do this.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_9">
  <Text>Charles de Gaulle</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_9_QUOTE">
  <Text>Faced with crisis, the man of character falls back on
  himself. He imposes his own stamp of action, takes responsibility
  for it, makes it his own.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_10">
  <Text>Simon Bolivar</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_10_QUOTE">
  <Text>Judgement comes from experience, and experience comes from
  bad judgement.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_11">
  <Text>Lech Walesa</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_11_QUOTE">
  <Text>He who puts out his hand to stop the wheel of history will
  have his fingers crushed.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_12">
  <Text>Ivan the Terrible</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_12_QUOTE">
  <Text>Withal, I concern myself greatly regarding the affairs of
  state, constant wars against hostile nations, and the welfare of
  my poor people.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_13">
  <Text>Henry VIII</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_13_QUOTE">
  <Text>My Lord, if it were not to satisfy the world, and my Realm,
  I would not do that I must do this day for none earthly
  thing.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_14">
  <Text>Herbert Hoover</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_14_QUOTE">
  <Text>Blessed are the young for they shall inherit the national
  debt.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_15">
  <Text>Louis XVI</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_15_QUOTE">
  <Text>Listeners never hear any good of themselves.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_16">
  <Text>Neville Chamberlain</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_16_QUOTE">
  <Text>In war, whichever side may call itself the victor, there
  are no winners, but all are losers.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_17">
  <Text>Andrew Jackson</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_17_QUOTE">
  <Text>There is no pleasure in having nothing to do; the fun is
  having lots to do and not doing it.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_18">
  <Text>Nero</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_18_QUOTE">
  <Text>So great an artist, I die!</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_19">
  <Text>Warren G. Harding</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_19_QUOTE">
  <Text>Somewhere there must be a book that tells all about it,
  where I could go to straighten it out in my mind. But I don't
  know where the book is, and maybe I couldn't read it if I found
  it.</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_20">
  <Text>Ethelred the Unready</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_20_QUOTE">
  <Text>Yeah, just five minutes, all right?</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_21">
  <Text>Dan Quayle</Text>
</Row>
<Row Tag="TXT_KEY_DQ_LEADER_NAME_21_QUOTE">
  <Text>If we don't succeed, we run the risk of failure.</Text>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

[A Northern Wind blog](http://halluphigh.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/civilization-v-quotes/) has a list of all the Civilization V quotations.

Comment: There's no quote that I need in the question! I need the `ranking quotes` at the end of the game.